# Simple AngularJS not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm just beginning to learn AngularJS and am following a tutorial. For some reason, it is displaying {{ name }}, instead of the name that I give it in the code below.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="js/main.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MyController">
            {{ name }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope)) {  
    $scope.name = "Hello World!";
}
```

Comment: Did you check the console...u must be getting some error

Comment: Need more details. How are you starting the application? Are you just opening the index.html file ?

Comment: remove once extra `)` added after `($scope)` and add it in the end after `}`. syntax error for `function` defined for `MyController`

Comment: And the semicolon! Thank you, that worked!

Answer (score 3):

the error i see is that you are putting the ) in the wrong place for the controller. try using the following

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
$scope.name = "Hello World!";
});
```